# Thousands separator in file having an localization error

Tags: c#

I'm a bit at a loss during a server migration where I moved my c# program from one server to another, the problem occured that the thousands separator suddenly changed without my doing. My guess is that its a localization error, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Both servers are equal in terms of languages installed, ... .

**Example:**
932Â 830,00   is shown on the new server instead of 932.830,00 like on the old

**Code:**

```
public void mydo(double difference, string filepath)
{
    StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
    fileContent.AppendLine("            " + String.Format("{0:n}", difference));

    using (StreamWriter fileHandler = new StreamWriter(filepath))
    {
        StringBuilder fileContent2 = new StringBuilder();

        fileContent2.AppendLine("<HTML><BODY>");
        fileContent2.Append(fileContent.ToString());
        fileContent2.AppendLine("</BODY></HTML>");

        fileHandler.Write(fileContent2.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is in `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator` property?

Comment: https://java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman: it's irrelevant in the article. It talsk about windows, not java per se.

Comment: A little explanation with the link would be useful then.

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman: I assumed someone would be able to click on the link and read it.......I can't spoon feed everyone.

Comment: Spooning required, don't do step 5.  Instead click on Additional Settings and fix the "Digit grouping symbol".   This might go wrong again when another program messes with this setting.  Looks like a utf8 mistake btw, if that helps narrow down the evildoer.

Comment: @vasily.sib  in notepad displayed as a blank. but could be a "control sign"

Comment: Looks like you've saved the file as Unicode/UTF8 and opened it as ascii, oh and the comma isn't a standard ascii comma but one from higher up the Unicode table

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are more problems here at the same time:

- It seems your local regional settings use non-break space as thousands separator and comma as decimal symbol. You should specify a culture in the `String.Format` or `Double.ToString` methods to use a specific culture. Rule of thumb: When formatting/parsing numbers *always* specify a culture (or the `InvariantCulture`) because the default culture comes from the the current regional settings, which can be different everywhere.
- The `"Â "` sequence is a typical sign that an UTF8 text is rendered with ISO-8859-1 or CP1250 (Latin1 8-bit) codepage. So maybe the dumped text is UTF8 (which is the default encoding of the .NET `StreamWriter` class), whereas if you don't specify the encoding of a HTML4 output it defaults to ISO-8859-1.
- And actually you want to use the dot as thousands separator and comma as decimal sign.

Explicitly using a culture (eg. German) can solve your problem with the number formatting:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
fileContent.Append(difference.ToString(culture));
```

But if the web page contains diacritical letters or other non-ASCII symbols the encoding issue will appear at other places. Make sure you configure both the `StreamWriter` and the output HTML content to use the same encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set your system's locale back to en-US as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2) says that results in the desired numeric format, which I can't help with because I don't know about your server configuration. Or, you can bypass your system locale with

```
String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:n}", difference);
```

Comment: setting the culture info works.  In my case I set it for the thread as a whole then after your answer: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");      what I'm confused about though is why it is a problem. As both servers (aside from the old being 2008 and the new one 2016) are identical.